# Build a dynamic SQL statement via $_POST

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So this is more about getting your opinion on the best approach for this.

I have what I think is quite an elegant way of building a simple dynamic SQL statement with a straightforward WHERE clause. The WHERE clause can include multiple fields but it is limited as it does not allow for **different** operators (comparative or logical).

I can build the following with this:

```
SELECT * from table_name WHERE field_1 = "value_1" AND field_2 = "value_2";
//or I can do
SELECT * from table_name WHERE field_1 = "value_1" OR field_2 = "value_2";
//or I can do
SELECT * from table_name WHERE field_1 <> "value_1" AND field_2 <> "value_2";
```

I can **not** build the following:

```
SELECT * from table_name WHERE field_1 = "value_1" AND field_2 <> "value_2";
//nor can I do
SELECT * from table_name WHERE field_1 = "value_1" AND field_2="value_2" OR field_3 = "value_3
```

It becomes a real problem when working with numbers and dates when I want to look for records with values between meaning I need to pass the same filed in twice with two separate values.... doesnt it?

```
SELECT * from table_name WHERE price BETWEEN 10 AND 20;
SELECT * from table_name WHERE date BETWEEN "2016-08-01" AND "2016-08-15";
```

And not forgetting multiple criteria with "IN" or LIKE statements which this also does not build, i.e.:

```
SELECT * from table_name WHERE field_1 IN("value_1","value_2, "value_3");
SELECT * from table_name WHERE field_1 LIKE "val%";
```

Here is what my current code looks like:

```
// db contains my DB connection
$db = new DB();

$where = 'WHERE';
$criteria = array();

foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $where = $where.' '.$key.'=? AND';
    array_push($criteria,$value);
}

if(count($_GET) > 0){
   // $sql will look like: SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE field_1 = ? AND field_2 = ?
   // $criteria is an array of values to pair with the above prepared statement. 
   // Will look like: $criteria("value_1", "value_2")
   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM mcl_data_gap '.$where;
   $results = $db->query($sql,$criteria);
} else {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM mcl_data_gap';
    $results = $db->query($sql);
}
// .... continue on using above SQL statement
```

In the above code I have used get but my assumption is post would also work.

The only idea I have come up with is to insert more key value pairs that contain the operators required in a coded format that would allow me to then look for these operators and build the statement based on them but I just feel like there is a better way and that is what I am hoping you can help with.

Another option I have just thought of is building the SQL before passing it to the server and just executing that.

Or can I post objects that contain the whole segment of the WHERE statement?

Comment: your code is vulnerable for SQL-injection. **don't ever trust user input**, not even as variable name. i had to try one time, because PHP automatically replaces spaces with underscores, but it does not replace tabs, which, however, mysql accepts as whitespace. so, someone unfriendly trying to query `yourfile.php?%27;DROP%09TABLE%09SomeImportantTable;%09--=a` will succeed in *aggressively slimming down* your database.

Comment: SQL injection is a problem here. A user could make the value of `$key` anything and cause a lot of problems for you. You can still build dynamic queries, but you should type out all of the SQL and just use the `$_GET` parameters to determine which pieces of SQL are used in the final query.

Comment: The SQL string and parameters are passed to a class which uses PDO prepared statements to query my db. My understanding was PDO prepared statements are used to protect against SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

You are using query parameters for the dynamic values (the right side of the equality comparison). This is good.

But you can't use a parameter for the dynamic *column names* (the left side of a comparison). This is how your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Prepared statements don't help with that.

The solution is to make sure every column name that comes from your $_GET keys is actually one of the columns in your table. In other words, this is called whitelisting the input.

```
$mcl_data_gap_columns = ["field_1", "field_2", "field_3"];
```

You only want to process $_GET parameters that match columns in your list of columns that exist in your table. Anything that isn't in this list should be ignored.

As for predicates that have multiple values, you can access them in PHP by naming the GET parameter with "`[]`" at the end.

```
$terms = [];
$parameters = [];

// only look for $_GET keys that match one of the known columns.
// this automatically ignores all other $_GET keys.
foreach ($mc_data_gap_columns as $col) {

  // get the single value, or the array of multiple values.
  // convert to an array in either case.
  if (isset($_GET[$col])) {
    $values = (array) $_GET[$col];
    $default_op = "=";
  } elseif (isset($_GET[$col."[]"])) {
    $values = $_GET[$col."[]"];
    $default_op = "IN";
  } else {
    continue;
  }

  // if your comparison is anything other than equality,
  // there should be another request parameter noting that.
  if (isset($_GET[$col."_SQLOP"])) {
    $op = $_GET[$col."_SQLOP"];
  } else {
    $op = $default_op;
  }
```

Process only the known operations. If $op is not one of the specific supported operations, ignore it or else throw an error.

```
  switch ($op) {
  case "=":
  case ">":
  case "<":
  case ">=":
  case "<=":
  case "<>":
    // all these are simple comparisons of one column to one value 
    $terms[] = "$col $op ?";
    $parameters[] = $values[0];
    break;
  case "BETWEEN":
    // comparisons of one column between two values 
    if (count($values) != 2) {
      error_log("$col BETWEEN: wrong number of arguments: " . count($values));
      die("Sorry, there has been an error in your request.");
    }
    $terms[] = "$col BETWEEN ? AND ?";
    $parameters[] = $values[0];
    $parameters[] = $values[1];
    break;
  case "IN":
    // comparisons of one column IN a list of any number of values
    $placeholders = implode(",", array_fill(1, count($values), "?"));
    $terms[] = "$col IN ($placeholders)";
    $parameters = array_merge($parameters, $values);
    break;
  default:
    error_log("Unknown operation for $col: $op");
    die("Sorry, there has been an error in your request.");
  }
}
```

Then finally after that's done, you'll know that $terms is either an empty array or else the array of search conditions.

```
if ($terms) {
  $sql .= " WHERE " . join(" AND ", $terms);
}

$db->query($sql, $parameters);
```

I have not tested the above code, but it should illustrate the idea:

- Never use $_GET input verbatim in your SQL queries
- Always filter input against a fixed list of safe values
- Or use `switch` to test against a fixed set of safe `case`s

> Another option I have just thought of is building the SQL before passing it to the server and just executing that.

No, no, no! This would just be an invitation to get hacked. Never do this!

Your wrong if you think that your HTML page is the only way someone can submit a request to your server. *Anyone* can form any URL they want, and submit it to your site, even if it contains GET parameters and values you don't expect.

Comment: Bill, you are of course correct and thanks for pointing that out, I should have recognised the weakness in my procedure myself. I shall take a moment to properly ingest what you have suggested and feedback on it.